# New Turkish Driving Licence is it valid in Denmark?

Tags: driving-license, denmark, turkish-citizens

According to many Turkish [recourses](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yeniehliyet.com%2Fnode%2F261&edit-text=&act=url) ([more official source](http://www.trafik.gov.tr/Sayfalar/SurucuIslem.aspx))
[new Turkish Driving Licence](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=yeni%20turkish%20driving%20licence&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=949&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidsta6se_RAhVKHxoKHQa3BGYQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=yeni%20%20ehliyet&imgrc=4iz6ErWOF-O7UM%3A)   is valid in many countries also Denmark .

But when I check Danish  [resources](http://www.fyidenmark.com/drivinglicense.html) they say Turkey is in Group 2 and my Turkish driving licence is only valid for three months.

I  think Turkish resources are wrong or I am missing something.

Can you clarify if Turkish Driving licence for normal residence is valid or not?

Comment: You are mistaking 2 non-related issues. Turkish driving licence is valid without limits for tourists and visitors. If you are a resident, you have 90 days to exchange your driving license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE